# How to view exactly what a process is doing?

Tags: viewer, process

Is there a handy utility/tool or way of seeing exactly what a Windows process is doing?

The problem I have is my company uses some external software to our stock control and accounting package to manage sales analysis and so on. The stock controlling/accounts software generates some CSV files and the analysis tool has an update utility to update it's own database. I'd like to be able to see exactly how far through the update process this utility is.

**Being able to examine the stream of data leaving the CSV files by this update utility's process would be ideal - is that possible?**

Having either company change or modify their update procedure is outside the scope of this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Will accept as the correct answer in 2 minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 3):

[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)

its the most handy and respected tool among administrators . Free ware, open source, lot of help info and easy customisations.

Process Hacker is a free and open source process viewer. This multi-purpose tool will assist you with debugging, malware detection and system monitoring. It includes powerful process termination, memory viewing/editing and other unique and specialized features.